# jQuery/JS extract a specific string from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following URL:

http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/search?search_keywords=Rome%2C+Italy&country=Italy&city=Rome&date_from=2016-07-02&date_to=2016-07-05

I only need to extract Rome from the url. So far I have managed to do this:

```
var citySearch = $.cookie('recentSearch');
citySearch.match(/_keywords=(.+)/)[1]
```

where citySearch the url.

This only returns "Rome%2C+Italy&country=Italy&city=Rome&date_from=2016-07-02&date_to=2016-07-05
"

Comment: Do you want `Rome` because it's the first part of the String, or because that's the value of the `city` GET variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex is matching too much, it should work with:

```
var citySearch = $.cookie('recentSearch');
citySearch.match(/_keywords=(.+?)&/)[1]
```

This would give you "Rome%2C+Italy" which is the keyword parameter.

hope this helps

Comment: I am only looking for "Rome"

Comment: meaning you just want to know if rome is included? in this case you could just 'citySearch.indexOf('Rome') >= 0'. If this is not the case, please describe your use case more specific...